# Using Bash - Repeat constants in for loop where multiple results are returned

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, constants

GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu).

I have a directory of files (multiple files per day) that I want to extract certain data from.

Each file has a series of values that are constant for the file (AuditID, ProcessID, etc) and appear one time for each file.
Then each file has many lines that begin with "STEP=XFR "

Goal: create a single line output that contains the constants mentioned above as well as each line that begins with "STEP=XFR ".

Issue: When I run the FOR LOOP to process the files, the constants are only echo'd once per file instead of on every line.

I've searched and searched (and am very new to bash) but haven't found the answer.

I got pretty close using sed to parse up the STEP=XFR lines where I somehow was able to include the constants within the substitution, but I poached most of the sed statement and I really didn't understand it so am opting for something that is more clear.

Currently I am attempting to simply output the un-parsed STEP=XFR lines while at the same time concatenating the constants in front of them.

Here is what I have... and many thanks.

```
region=$1
log_date=$2

cur_date=`date +%Y%m%d`

if [[ -z $1 ]]; then
    region=$Region
fi

if [[ -z $2 ]]; then
    log_date=$cur_date
fi

#define location of source file
file_loc='/bl/project/'$region'/netezza/log'

#declare directory/file mask
files=$file_loc'/LOG_nz_flow_execute_svckmnz_elt_'$log_date'*.log'

#define file name and location to put results 
xfrmon_results="/home/userid/quality/xfrmon_"$region"_"$log_date".dat"

#loop through files...
for f in $files
do
#grep for values
d='|'
AuditID=$(grep "^Audit ID" $f | cut -d':' -f2 | head -n 1)
ProcessID=$(grep "^Process ID" $f | cut -d':' -f2 | head -n 1)
xfrmeta=$(grep "STEP=XFR " $f)

lineout="$region$d$log_date$d$AuditID$d$ProcessID$d$xfrmeta"

echo "$lineout"

done
```

**results:**

1. prd|20130922| 8900983| 7718|
2. prd|20130922| 8900984| 12248|STEP=XFR Start=2013-09-22
   03:30:08.493374    End=2013-09-22 03:30:08.988577  Duration(secs)=1 
   Written=[1]
3. STEP=XFR Start=2013-09-22 05:09:54.014299    End=2013-09-22
   05:09:56.610330  Duration(secs)=2   Written=[1]
4. STEP=XFR Start=2013-09-22 05:09:51.886866    End=2013-09-22
   05:09:52.539379  Duration(secs)=1   Written=[1]
5. STEP=XFR Start=2013-09-22 05:09:51.831049    End=2013-09-22
   05:09:52.319850  Duration(secs)=1   Written=[1]
6. prd|20130922| 8900985| 11316|
7. prd|20130922| 8900986| 989|
8. prd|20130922| 8900987| 1977|
9. prd|20130922| 8900988| 25269|STEP=XFR Start=2013-09-22
   05:45:07.923100    End=2013-09-22 05:45:08.299312  Duration(secs)=1 
   Written=[1]
10. STEP=XFR Start=2013-09-22 06:11:43.464400    End=2013-09-22
     06:11:47.741536  Duration(secs)=4   Written=[1]
11. prd|20130922| 8900989| 8962|STEP=XFR Start=2013-09-22
     05:50:10.625196    End=2013-09-22 05:51:49.113589 
     Duration(secs)=99   Written=[62617537]
12. STEP=XFR Start=2013-09-22 05:51:49.195200    End=2013-09-22
     05:51:51.322727  Duration(secs)=2   Written=[0]
13. STEP=XFR Start=2013-09-22 05:51:51.558343    End=2013-09-22
     05:52:12.234552  Duration(secs)=21   Written=[62617537]
14. prd|20130922| 8900990| 9061|STEP=XFR Start=2013-09-22
     05:51:17.891031    End=2013-09-22 05:51:18.923637  Duration(secs)=2
     Written=[82]

**desired results:** (region, log_date, AuditID & ProcessID repeat themselves each time STEP=XFR is echo'd.)

1. prd|20130922| 8900983| 7718|
2. prd|20130922| 8900984| 12248|STEP=XFR Start=2013-09-22
   03:30:08.493374    End=2013-09-22 03:30:08.988577  Duration(secs)=1 
   Written=[1]
3. prd|20130922| 8900984| 12248|STEP=XFR Start=2013-09-22
   05:09:54.014299    End=2013-09-22 05:09:56.610330  Duration(secs)=2 
   Written=[1]
4. prd|20130922| 8900984| 12248|STEP=XFR Start=2013-09-22
   05:09:51.886866    End=2013-09-22 05:09:52.539379  Duration(secs)=1 
   Written=[1]
5. prd|20130922| 8900984| 12248|STEP=XFR Start=2013-09-22
   05:09:51.831049    End=2013-09-22 05:09:52.319850  Duration(secs)=1 
   Written=[1]
6. prd|20130922| 8900985| 11316|
7. prd|20130922| 8900986| 989|
8. prd|20130922| 8900987| 1977|
9. prd|20130922| 8900988| 25269|STEP=XFR Start=2013-09-22
   05:45:07.923100    End=2013-09-22 05:45:08.299312  Duration(secs)=1 
   Written=[1]
10. prd|20130922| 8900988| 25269|STEP=XFR Start=2013-09-22
     06:11:43.464400    End=2013-09-22 06:11:47.741536  Duration(secs)=4
     Written=[1]
11. prd|20130922| 8900989| 8962|STEP=XFR Start=2013-09-22
     05:50:10.625196    End=2013-09-22 05:51:49.113589 
     Duration(secs)=99   Written=[62617537]
12. prd|20130922| 8900989| 8962|STEP=XFR Start=2013-09-22
     05:51:49.195200    End=2013-09-22 05:51:51.322727  Duration(secs)=2
     Written=[0]
13. prd|20130922| 8900989| 8962|STEP=XFR Start=2013-09-22
     05:51:51.558343    End=2013-09-22 05:52:12.234552 
     Duration(secs)=21   Written=[62617537]
14. prd|20130922| 8900990| 9061|STEP=XFR Start=2013-09-22
     05:51:17.891031    End=2013-09-22 05:51:18.923637  Duration(secs)=2
     Written=[82]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your `for` loop to this one:

```
#loop through files...
for f in $files; do
    #grep for values
    d='|'
    AuditID=$(grep "^Audit ID" "$f" | cut -d':' -f2 | head -n 1)
    ProcessID=$(grep "^Process ID" "$f" | cut -d':' -f2 | head -n 1)

    while read -r xfrmeta; do
        echo "$region$d$log_date$d$AuditID$d$ProcessID$d$xfrmeta"
    done < <(exec grep "STEP=XFR " "$f")
done

It would create an instance of a line for every line in the output of grep using process substitution and `while read` loop.
```

I also recommend storing your file paths in array as well to prevent unexpected word splitting and pathname expansion:

```
files=("/path/to/file1" "/path/to/file1" ...)
for f in "${files[@]}"; do
```